# Add files to tar in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a static method add files to existing `tar.gz` but each time I run it there is only one log file with lastrun time name.. So it creates file and removes all files in .tar.gz before add it. 
But I want to keep them all. This is why I renamed files with current datetimes

But I miss something here , what's that ?

```
AccessLog.AccessLog.backupAccessLog("mytarfile.tar.gz","example.log")
```

definition:

```
class AccessLog:
    @staticmethod
    def backupAccessLog(output_filename, logfile):
        backupTar = tarfile.open(output_filename,"w:gz")
        newlogfile=logfile+"_"+time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        copyfile(logfile,newlogfile)
        backupTar.add(newlogfile)
        backupTar.close()
        os.remove(newlogfile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation clearly states that appending to a compressed file is not possible:

> Note that 'a:gz' or 'a:bz2' is not possible. If mode is not suitable to open a certain (compressed) file for reading, ReadError is raised. Use mode 'r' to avoid this. If a compression method is not supported, CompressionError is raised.

The reason for this is that compression is done after tarring on the level of the complete tar file. So the individual files, and the structure of the tarfile cannot be accessed without (full) decompression. This is different from `.zip` files where compression takes place on the individual file level and the index (meta-data) is always accessible and can be extended without affecting the rest of the file.

For `.tar.gz` files you would need to decompress the tar file (but not extract the individual files) then add the files and compress. This can be done on the fly (although costly in computing power requirements), but not with the tarfile module alone, you would need to do the decompression, compresssion yourself and handle the in memory tarfile extension.

Answer (score 0):

Originally -

```
backupTar = tarfile.open(output_filename,"w:gz")
```

That is the problem - you should open it in 'append mode' `"a:gz"`. This is not supported.

So one can write a wrapper like the following

```
def add_to_tar(tar_name, file_name):

    if not os.path.exists(tar_name):
        t1 = tarfile.open(tar_name, 'w:gz')
        t1.close()

    t1 = tarfile.open(tar_name, 'r:gz')
    tmp = '_' + tar_name
    t2 = tarfile.open(tmp, 'w:gz')
    t1.extractall()
    for m in t1.members:
        t2.add(m)
        os.remove(m.path) # careful about this, this deletes the locally extracted file 
    t2.add(file_name)
    t2.close()
    t1.close()
    os.remove(file_name) # remove the file added to tar
    os.rename(tmp, tar_name)
```

And then one can call this

```
add_to_tar(output_filename, newlogfile)
```

That should work.

Comment: I tried it this error occurred: "ValueError: mode must be 'r' or 'w'"

Comment: Yeah !! Got it! :( I thought that mode may be supported.

Comment: Fixed - and wrote a wrapper to do what you'd like to do. Painful - but doesn't appear a simpler way with tarfile python API

Comment: Nope that doesn't work as well!! I was trying to avoid - reading a gzip and writing again - but looks like that's the only way to go about it!

Comment: Mostly the above code should work. Tried with a few files (note: it deletes the files that are added to the tar). But this is painfully slow. Ideally do something like this in a temp directory - and move the final .tar.gz file to your desired destination